# Replace specific index in list inside dictionary?

Tags: python

how to replace specific index in list inside dictionary?

I have

```
dictionary = { "one" : 1, values : [2, 3, "apples", 4]}
```

I want to change "apples" into "pears", how do I do that?

Comment: `dictionary[values][2] = "pears"`

Comment: Do you know how to access a dict? Do you know how to access a list? With what exactly are you struggling? Is the index of `apples` known?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do:

- If you know the specific index of the value you wish you replace you can simply do:

  ```
  dictionary['values'][2] = "pears"
  ```
- If the specific index is always in question but the value you wish to replace is known, you can use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) like so:

  ```
  dictionary['values'][dictionary['values'].index('apples')] = "pears"
  ```

Also just an FYI, your dict "values" entry should be surrounded by quotes or you will get an error in this example.

```
dictionary = { "one" : 1, "values" : [2, 3, "apples", 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's always in a list but can be in different places in that list and under different keys in the dict you can use this:

```py
     def apples_to_pears(dictionary):
          for key, value in dictionary.items():
              if isinstance(value, list):
                  dictionary[key]=["pears" if i == "apples" else i for i in value]
```